While upgrading webapp from angular14 to angular17 facing indexedDB issue : "ReferenceError: indexedDB is not defined"
My webapp was in angular14, there indexedDB working smoothly , but recently while upgrading to angular17 this issue occuring "ReferenceError: indexedDB is not defined" at DB creation point "let openDB = indexedDB.open('idbData');"
Although "declare var indexedDB: IDBFactory;" is present in node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts
code:
constructor( private http:HttpClient){
 this.createDB();
};
createDB(){
    let openDB = indexedDB.open('idbData');    
    openDB.onupgradeneeded = (e:any) => {
      let db = openDB.result;
      let req1 = db.createObjectStore("year_store", 
                 {"keyPath":'YEAR'});
      req1.createIndex("year_idx", "YEAR", {unique: true});      
    }
  }

Thanks in advance for any productive help.

Please be nice and don't post screenshots of code. It discourages people to engage.
You can wrap any text in a code block. It's easier for people to edit or test your code as it is. Thanks!
